# pointer to void into smart pointer

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

I am trying to create a QScopedPointer of void with a custom deleter to properly managed resources coming from a C library (which does only supply void* to its internal data structures).
However, when I try to instantiate a QScopedPointer of void, I get this error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h:104:14:
error: cannot form a reference to 'void'
    inline T &operator*() const
(from Clang)
```

or this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qscopedpointer.h:104:
error: forming reference to void
(from GCC)
```

I thought to specialize QScopedPointer or to write a basic scoped pointer with custom deleter, but in both cases I end up duplicated exactly the same code that I have in QScopedPointer.

Is there any way I can get rid (or specialize) that particular function so that the compiler does not complain anymore?

Comment: I would write a custom scoped-ptr-to-void and delegate the implementation to QScopedPointer-to-char.

Comment: Create a dummy type `struct MYDUMMY{}`, cast the `void*` to `MYDUMMY*`, and specialise on that. The problems will go away. You may want to create inline wrappers for the C functions so everything types nicely.

Comment: Usually you either know _what sort of data_ you are storing (and can use that type of pointer, instead of `void`), or do not own pointer (and then scoped pointer have no sence). Are you sure you need scoped pointer of `void*`?

Comment: Unfortunately the type I want to delete is defines as void*:

https://github.com/mm2/Little-CMS/blob/2f31157590e1121f047404eb4c41768b56b697c8/include/lcms2.h

Line 608

Comment: You can't delete a void pointer.  You have to cast it back to it's original type before you can delete it.  How is the original memory allocated?  I suspect it was by malloc (since you're writing a custom deleter) and you're going to use free to clean it up.  Try casting your void pointer, say, to a char pointer when you pass it to the constructor.

Comment: No, it does not use malloc. cmsHPROFILE is the return value of several functions of LCMS2. An HPROFILE is freed using cmsCloseProfile() (which will be the body of my custom deleter). The same is true for cmsHTRANSFORM.

Comment: BTW, I've already implemented something that does the trick here: http://qtpfsgui.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=qtpfsgui/qtpfsgui;a=blob;f=src/Viewers/LdrViewer.cpp;h=b42dd6522bc5a61755869fa64ba1924f23939706;hb=HEAD (between Line 60 and 76). However, I wished I could use QScopedPointer instead of rewriting it without T& operator*() const;

Comment: Why can't you cast your void pointer to a char pointer and create a QScopedPointer?  Any *use* of the pointer (including clean up) has to cast it back to void which I think will occur automatically.  Meaning you only have to do the cast when you create the scoped pointer.

Comment: You are really complicating things unnecessarily here. It would be easier to just create your own simple auto pointer for this type then to coerce a library type that is not designed for this.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to write that function such that it won't blow the compiler's mind out.  You should ask yourself what sense it would make anyway.  How can a smart pointer to void do something inherently impossible to do with a void*?

```
void * vptr; *vptr = ??;  ?? = *vptr;  f(*vptr);
```

None of those statements make any sense at all.

The void* type is a very special type meant to provide opaque typing in C.  You can use it in C++ but usually you don't want to.  I have a feeling that whatever you're trying to do, there's a better way.

If you really need an opaque pointer type that is smart, you'll have to make it and you'll have to ommit dereferencing functionality.

What kind of surprises me is that C++ compilers are required to not compile member functions of templates that are not used.  This would indicate to me that you are actually trying to dereference a void pointer.  You can't do that.  If you want the pointer out of a smart pointer you use get().  I'm sure QScopedPointer or whatever has a similar function.